# i want to make temp value and store array and display it in screen in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**code**

```
function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    //console.log("insideFunction Row1"+Player); 
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      //var pushValue;    
      tempObj = [response.data];
      // console.log("tempObj", tempObj);
      for ( var i = 0; i <= tempObj.length; i++) {
        //console.log("forLoop", tempObj[i]);
        temp.push(tempObj[i]);
      }
       console.log("temp", temp);
      Postdata(temp);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
```

[image: Console Imge]

I want to remove undefined for FORLOOP and want to  display 1 temp value in console so that i can easily map the value in table row
Please help me Provide some help/Code
I don't  know why 4 time temp data appear

i just want display this type of arrayofObject no repeat no undefined  value
[image: display this temp]

I have this type of data
{
"Status": 1000,
"Properties": {
"ClipName": "Clip1",
"Upcounter": "15:33:44:33",
"DownCounter": "16:33:44:33",
"ChannelName": "Channel1",
"StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
"PlayerName": "Vtr1",
"Duration": "12:00:00:01"
}
}
{
"Status": 1000,
"Properties": {
"ClipName": "Clip3",
"Upcounter": "12:33:44:33",
"DownCounter": "12:33:44:33",
"ChannelName": "Channel3",
"StartTimeCode": "00:00:00:00",
"PlayerName": "Vtr3",
"Duration": "12:00:00:01"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try this

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= tempObj.length; i++) {        
    if (tempObj[i] !== undefined) {
        temp.push(tempObj[i]);
    }
}
```

Another way is that you can use map() method
see this example

```
    const aar1=[
        {status:'sts1',properties:'prop1'},
        undefined,
        {status:'sts2',properties:'prop2'},
        undefined,
        {status:'sts3',properties:'prop3'},
        undefined,
        {status:'sts4',properties:'prop4'},
        undefined,
        {status:'sts5',properties:'prop5'},
    ]

    const aar2= aar1.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== undefined;        
   });
```

console.log('new array', aar2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems data returned by api might contain invalid things. try below(just replace loop section):

```
for ( let i = 0; i < tempObj.length; i++) {
        //console.log("forLoop", tempObj[i]);
        if(tempObj[i] != undefined) temp.push(tempObj[i]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this would help you if I got you right

```
function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    const data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {   
        response.data.map(item => {
            if(item.Properties){
              temp.push(item);
            }
        })
      Postdata(temp);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: response.data.map is not a function i get this error in console

Comment: really cool first answer you've and congrats! In this answer it would be helpful to describe the reason why the OP's code is failing and why you think this code would work - always bonus points for linking documentation as well for future readers.

Comment: @ANITAKUMARI console log the response.data and see if it is array , if it's not use a array structure to map on it like I did

Comment: @Wally Thanks For The Advice, I would definitely do this in future